# Disabling attachements in lists

Tags: list, custom-list, attachments

I'd like tu turn off attachments in my custom list definitions. In order to do that, I specified `DisableAttachments="TRUE"` whenever it was possible: in list definitions *Schema.xml* and in *Elements.xml*, but I still see the *Attach file* button on the ribbon and still can attach files. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DisableAttachments="TRUE"` on the top of Schema.xml and you should be good to go:

For e.g.

```
<List Title="Test List" Description="Test desc" Direction="0" BaseType="0" Url="Lists/TestList" DisableAttachments="TRUE" FolderCreation="FALSE" Version="8" Type="100" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your list being created by a list instance deployed alongside the list definition?

If so, the list instance can override the definition properties.